# Combining SED commands

Tags: linux, shell, sed

Combine sed commands into one command

I am currently doing these two commands

removes the first character of each line

```
sed -i 's/\(.\{1\}\)//'
```

removes extra spaces in each line

```
sed -i 's/    / /g'
```

There are 3.4 BILLION lines in the 237GB file it is parsing, and i dont want it to need to run through twice.

Comment: Command will look like sed -i 's/\(.\{1\}\)//;'s/    / /g'   
Found out you just need to use a semicolon. Sorry for clogging up boards.

Comment: How is the first command different from `sed -i 's/.//'`?

Comment: Honestly don't know, found the command on a previous stackoverflow question and it worked so i didnt question it.

Comment: The `{1}` quantifier is completely pointless. You probably got it from some PHP guru...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below sed command would combine the both. Use `;` as separator to combine two sed operations.

```
sed -i 's/\(.\{1\}\)//;s/    / /g' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
sed  -i -e 's/\(.\{1\}\)//' -e 's/    / /g'  file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try an `awk`

```
awk '{sub(/./,"");$1=$1}1' file
```

`sub(/./,"")` removes first character
`$1=$1` removes all double space.

Comment: is one way inherently faster than another? I am going for speed because of the size of the file.

Comment: Also can awk edit files in place? Doesn't help me too much if it cant because the I/O time to copy the file is to high.

Comment: `awk` does not do in place edit. You can do `awk 'code' file > tmp & mv tmp file`. For speed, you need to test.